# How to validate a credentials provider

Tags: libgit2sharp

Given a combination of user and password I want to determine of this results in a valid `UsernamePasswordCredentials` for a known remote git server.

Ideally I would like to be able to do that irrespective of whether a local checkout has occurred.

What I have tried is this.  I have a class with the following methods

```
    private CredentialsHandler UserPassCredentialsProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (_gitPass == null)
                throw new System.Exception("No git Credentials have been supplied");

            var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
            {
                Username = _gitUser,
                Password = _gitPass
            };

            return (_url, _usr, _cred) => credentials;
        }
    } 


    public bool CheckCredentials()
    {
        try
        {  
            using (var repo = new Repository(Path.Combine(WorkingCopyRoot, "MyRepo")))
            {
                IEnumerable<Reference> refs = Repository.ListRemoteReferences(Path.Combine(WorkingCopyRoot, "MyRepo"), UserPassCredentialsProvider);

                return refs != null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is just the code I have at time of writing - I have been hacking away at this for a while now, however, the `ListRemoteReferences()` appears to work equally with or without a valid password.

It does not appear straighforward to achieve what I want - any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty close.  By switching the path from local to remote I was able to get it working as I would like.  In the code below `RepoRoot` is a URL.

```
public bool CheckCredentials()
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<Reference> refs = Repository.ListRemoteReferences(Path.Combine(RepoRoot, "MyRepo"), UserPassCredentialsProvider);

        return refs != null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```